# CellMeasurer with function child ({ measure }) => <div />) renders excessive number of times

Tags: react-virtualized

REF: demo at https://codesandbox.io/s/1vy7ljo877

The demo uses 2 approaches to render some images.

The first row renders an element inside CellMeasurer 
while the second row renders a function with signature: ({ measure }) => )

I find that for the function render, while the size is calculated correctly, the render method gets called n^2 # of times where n is approximately the number of items that it tries to display.

If deferredMeasurementCache is turned on, the problem gets exponentially worse since n becomes the size of the collection.

The above results in crazy long page load times and very sluggish behavior when scrolling.

Is this normal behavior or am I implementing the function inside CellMeasurer incorrectly?

Answer (score 2):

> If deferredMeasurementCache is turned on, the problem gets exponentially worse since n becomes the size of the collection.

If you're not passing the `CellMeasurerCache` to `Grid` as a `deferredMeasurementCache` prop, then `Grid` isn't guaranteed to work correctly. It's necessary for it to know about the cache for a couple of cases. (Maybe check out [this part of the docs](https://github.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized/blob/master/docs/CellMeasurer.md#performance) to make sure you aren't misunderstanding how `CellMeasurer` is supposed to work when used to calculate the width/height of a row/column.)

That being said, what you're describing *sounds* like a bug, but I'm not sure it actually is. At a high level, it's caused by the [`CellMeasurer` `measure` method calling `Grid.recomputeGridSize()`](https://github.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized/blob/a23762e3d813be5248fd8420ea95512abcd0789d/source/CellMeasurer/CellMeasurer.js#L137-L141) which synchronously triggers `forceUpdate()` (causing all visible cells to re-render).

At first I thought the solution might be to just debounce or queue a `setState` action instead. Unfortunately that only pushes the problem away a little; the possibility still exists. I can't debounce for too long, or I risk the `Grid` showing cells to the user that are clearly the wrong size. (A debounce that's too big might even allow a user to keep scrolling ahead of it, outrunning the re-render.) It's also possible that images will load far apart (after a delay) in a real app, defeating any debounce I might do anyway.

The problem here is that any time a cell reports it has a different size, the `Grid` needs to relayout the other cells (potentially shifting them up or down). In this simple example it seems unnecessary- because all images end up having a uniform width and height. This isn't typical though. Since you've configured your `CellMeasurerCache` to measure height, and since the height of each column impacts the height of the row (and thus all other columns, as explained in the docs I linked to above), `Grid` has to re-render all cells each time one reports a change.

Put another way, if you added more rows, *and* changed your example to be more like this:

```
const makeImages = (count=10, startIndex=0) => {
  const width = 100;
  const imagesArray = _.times(count, (index) => {
    const height = 100 + Math.round(Math.random() * 200);
    return {
      key: startIndex+index,
      src: `http://placehold.it/${width}x${height}/${((1<<24)*Math.random()|0).toString(16)}/fff?text=${startIndex+index}`,
    }
  });

  return imagesArray;
};
```

Then maybe it's easier to see why a change to a cell in row 1, column 1 could potential impact the height of all cells in row 1, and the position of all cells in the grid.